# Sharepoint 2010, easy to to overwrite duplicate list item during insert

Tags: 2010

With Sharepoint 2010, non duplicates can be enforced at the site column / list definition level (a unique index).

Is there a built in way to do instead of failing with "duplicates not allowed", during an insert. Is it possible to instead replace that list item.

I can manually do this with a bit of custom code, but I'm wondering if there is a build in way to do this using the object model / caml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to implement this on your own. That is check if the unique value exists and then either add or update.